# Do we neccesarily need two variables when reparameterizing a double integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

So, recently I was trying to derive beta function from convolution of gamma function, that is,

$$ I = \int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x} \, dx$$

$$ J = \int_0^\infty y^m e^{-y} \, dy$$

$$ I\cdot J = \iint\limits_R x^n y^m e^{-x} e^{-y} \,dA$$

Now, our goal is to get

$$ \int_0^1 t^{v-1} (1-t)^{u-1} dt = \frac{ \Gamma (v) \Gamma(u)}{ \Gamma (u+v)}.$$

So, I thought of putting

$ x=(t)$
and,
$ y= 1-t$

Then, I am wondering what happens to the dA area element. **Is it necessary we need two variables when do coordinate shift for double integral? Why or why not?**

[Proof for contrast in wiki:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Derivatives)

Comment: It's not possible to parameterise a two dimensional region with one parameter.

Comment: In your first three integrals you use the letters $x$ and $y$ as bounded variables with respect to which you integrate, and in your last integral, from $0$ to $1,$ you treat them as constants. Your notation is confusing.

Comment: First, I would change variables to polar coordinates and do the radial integral. This will get you an integral of trig functions, which after substituting $t=\sin\theta$ or $t=\cos\theta$ would get you a one variable integral from $0$ to $1$

Comment: @PeterForeman yes, that's what I'm struggling with. If you can write an answer explainign that aspect then I'd gladly accept it

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
\Gamma(n)\Gamma(m) = \iint\limits_R x^{n-1} y^{m-1} e^{-(x+y)} \,dA.
$$
If $u = x+y$ and $v=\dfrac x{x+y}$ (so that $1-v=\dfrac y {x+y}$) then $0\le v\le 1$ and $u\ge0.$ Then you need to think about the Jacobian.

That will do it.